# JUnitPerf Sample XML

Tags: xml, junit, hudson, junitperf

I have a custom stats module for some load tests on a prototype app, and I'm trying to get them into a Hudson CI server. Hudson can read JUnitPerf XML output, but I don't know what that XML looks like. Does anyone have some sample output from junit they could send, or know of links to where I could find the docs?